# Clicking multiple buttons on same page with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am very new to Python and Selenium. I am using chromedriver.
I need some help. I have a web page unfortunately I cannot show it because it's blocked to be opened from everyone but locally at work. Basically it is a web page where there are around 15 buttons (same class) and when clicked the button disappears. I want to make a code that will click on every single button one by one until they are all clicked (disappeared). Then refresh the page and do the same for the next 100 pages.

Comment: No you cant, when click 1 browser and Dom wil change, have to click, go back get again buttons and continue click

Answer (score 0):

What I found to work for me is this, I found similar question here and one of the answers was this. Not sure how actually this works and why I have to use specific numbers for buttons because if I use buttons[4].click() it won't work.

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn default check check green markAsChecked']")
buttons[2].click()

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn default check check green markAsChecked']")
buttons[3].click()

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn default check check green markAsChecked']")
buttons[5].click()

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn default check check green markAsChecked']")
buttons[7].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't have your page to test this code so let's hope it works..

you can get all buttons in page within a list and then make a loop to click all list items .. it should looks like that:

```
# this will return a list with all buttons
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn default check check green markAsChecked']")

# clicking loop
for button in buttons:
button.click()
```

you may need to add a small delay between clicks because it bugs sometime in selenium.. just try first without delay .. if it doesn't work add `sleep(0.5)` in loop or make it click with javascript

Comment: If there is a page refresh after button click, all your elements is your array get stale.

Comment: he said in comments that page is not refreshed and button clicks doesn't affect the page

Comment: That is an assumption from the OP. I wouldn't rely on that.So far I haven't seen a single line of his code or the page source. The button disappears. Is it hidden by css, removed by js, or is it a page refresh? We don't know.

Comment: yes you're right .. that's why we need the page source at least